# WooCommerce в карточке товара в значения атрибутов пусто

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, атрибуты, корзина

Атрибуты к товару пустые, при том что по умолчанию стоят

[image: 1].
[image: Верный XHTML].
Проблема: в корзине не показывает значения атрибутов ($item_data = $cart_item['data'];), список атрибутов есть а значений нет, далее при заказе так же, сообщение заказ оформлен тоже нет значений и вот только в письме клиенту "заказ оформлен" и в админке woocommerce появляются значения атрибутов.
Кто сталкивался с таким и как это исправить???
Нужно в корзине, оформление заказа и заказ оформлен показать значения атрибутов.